Stop images that are too small appearing in Google Merchant Center
We have lots of products in the merchant center that show images that are too small with the error:
Image too small. Use an image that's at least 100x100 pixels for non-apparel and 250x250 pixels for apparel products:
An example of the images for a product is:

The first picture is a thumbnail, and the second is the actual picture to use.  These products are detected automatically from our website.  The product above is available here:
https://www.construct.net/en/game-assets/sounds/music/fantasy-medieval-music-loops-1070
The product schema for this item only lists one image (the larger one):
{
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Fantasy & Medieval Music Loops",
  "category": "Media > Music & Sound Recordings > Digital Music Downloads",
  "image": [
    "https://construct-static.com/uploads/97578/29f0a8a4-1516-465a-8e2f-020148741d1c/card%20img.jpg"
  ]

Why is Google taking the thumbnail picture, and using it even though it's not valid or specified in the schema?  Is there any way I can tell Google to not use the thumbnail image?  Going through manually removing them is too laborious and the product details should be being updated automatically without intervention.

This has been out here for a bit. Has it been resolved? If not, looking at the meta for the page, even though you are only showing the larger image within the page, you are referencing the thumbnails in the Open Graph and Twitter tags. I believe this is where Google is getting the second image. Much like @Evgeny below, update the og and twitter graphs to have the larger image and request a recrawl.

Try the following.
First, write in Open Graph and Twitter tags for the desired image - this is done in the <head> of the page:
<meta property="og:image" content="https://construct-static.com/uploads/97578/29f0a8a4-1516-465a-8e2f-020148741d1c/card%20img.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://construct-static.com/uploads/97578/29f0a8a4-1516-465a-8e2f-020148741d1c/card%20img.jpg">

And then put a data-nosnippet for thumbnails so Google doesn't count them for snippets:
<img src="example.jpg" data-nosnippet>


data-nosnippet does not work on img tags. And I suspect the merchant centre crawler does not take it into account anyhow, as the snippet relates to the text displayed in search results. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag#data-nosnippet-attr
